# Method of Moments for $p(x) = cx^{\beta} \hspace{1cm} x \in[0,a] $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

**Problem:** Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf  $$p(x)= \left \{
  \begin{matrix}{}
  cx^{\beta} \hspace{1cm} x \in[0,a] \\
  0 \hspace{1cm} \text{otherwise} \\ 
  \end{matrix}
\right.$$
where $a > 0$, $\beta > -1$ are unknown and $c$ is the normalizing constant. Find the estimator of $a$ and $\beta$ using the method of moments.

**Attempt:** I found $$\left \{
  \begin{matrix}{}
  \frac{X_1 + X_2+\cdots+X_n}{n}=\frac{ca^{\beta+2}}{\beta +2}  \\
  \frac{X_1^2 + X_2^2+\cdots+X_n^2}{n}=\frac{ca^{\beta+3}}{\beta +3}  \\ 
  \end{matrix}
\right.$$
but I can't continue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $$c  = \frac{\beta+1}{a^{\beta+1}}.$$
Consequently (presuming that your calculations are right),
$$E[X] = \frac{ca^{\beta+2}}{\beta+2}=\frac{\beta+1}{\beta+2}a,$$
and
$$E[X^2] = \frac{ca^{\beta+3}}{\beta+3}=\frac{\beta+1}{\beta+3}a^2.$$
Also,
$$\frac{E[X]^2}{E[X^2]}=\frac{(\beta+1)(\beta+3)}{(\beta+2)^2} = 1-\frac{1}{(\beta+2)^2} \implies \beta = -2 + \sqrt{\frac{E[X^2]}{E[X^2]-E[X]^2}}.$$
Can you find $a$?